# Ramda - R.Both with functions taking different number of params

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Just learning Ramda and find I keep running into this same scenario.   I have 2 conditional functions that I want to evaluate with R.both.   The twist is that 1 function will require an extra parameter.   Something like:

`const condition1 = (y) => y===1;`

`const condition2 = (x, y) => x===y;`

`const validator = R.both(condition1, condition2)`

Notice that the parms for condition2 are switched.   If I know that `x` will be applied first this works fine.  But what if it isn't?

Do I:

1)  alter condition1 like `const conditionAltered = () => condition1`

2)  use some Ramda function to do the same (not sure what that would be)

3)  ????

Looking for a "best practice" type answer.

---

OK, so as it turns out I completely misunderstood how the `R.both` operated.   First I thought it would auto-curry the passed in conditions and second I didn't realize it short-circuited.

Given that my (1) should read `const conditionAltered = (x, y) => condition1(y)`

Comment: I think there is some typo mistakes in conditions. Can you please confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if the conditions in questions are correct but I will try my best to give a solution.

Let above conditions are like following.

```
const condition1 = (x) => x === 2;
const condition2 = (x, y) => x > y;
```

To check both the conditions, you can do

```
const validator = R.both(condition1, condition2);
validator(2, 1) // return `true`
```

Now if you want to invert the arguments of `condition2`, then you can do like following

```
const condition1 = (x) => x === 2;
const condition2 = (y, x) => x > y;
const validator = R.both(condition1, R.flip(condition2));
validator(2, 1) // return `true`
```

Note, I have added [`R.flip()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip) to flip the arguments.

Comment: As I noted above my original question didn't make sense because I did not really understand how R.both worked.  Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

As Vipin Kumar demonstrates, you can flip the arguments of one function, but if that has the order you would prefer, then you can alter the other function.

```
const evenWidth = (width) => width % 2 === 0 
const tall = (height, width) => height > width

// (width, height) => boolean
const evenTall = both(evenWidth, flip(tall))

// (height, width) => boolean
const tallEven = both(tall, (_, width) => evenWidth(width))
```

If you really wanted a point-free version of the latter, you could do this instead:

```
const tallEven = both(tall, compose(evenWidth, nthArg(1)))
```

But I find the original easier to read.

Comment: Didn't realize one could use the '_'.   This is an improvement on my restated (1)  so marking as correct.

Comment: The "`_`" is just a legal variable name; it does not have the special placeholder properties it would in some other languages.

Comment: Well *that's* the only dumb thing you've said. :-)  learning something new should never make you feel dumb for not having known it before!